# wso2is 5.4.1 + liferay 6.2ga6

Tags: liferay-6, wso2-identity-server

I followed official documentation from : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS541/Integrating+WSO2+Identity+Server+with+Liferay to Login in my Liferay Portal with wso2is user, but it not work for me in wso2is-5.4.1 and liferay6.2ga6. When I try login, liferay's log print "Primary URL :https://wso2is.local:9443/services/Secondary URL :null" but no call to wso2is server is done.

I added this lines into my portal-ext.properties :

auth.pipeline.pre=org.wso2.liferay.is.authenticator.WSO2ISAuthenticator auth.pipeline.enable.liferay.check=false wso2is.auth.service.endpoint.primary=https://wso2is.local:9443/services/ wso2is.auth.thrift.endpoint=localhost wso2is.auth.thrift.port=10500 wso2is.auth.thrift.connection.timeout=10000 wso2is.auth.thrift.admin.user=admin wso2is.auth.thrift.admin.user.password=admin wso2is.auth.thrift.endpoint.login=https://wso2is.local:9443/ wso2is.auth.thrift.system.trusstore=/wso2is-5.4.1/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks wso2is.auth.thrift.system.trusstore.password=wso2carbon

Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, a lot of the WSO2 documentation is very crufty, containing articles that have been pulled forward from previous versions of the documentation without regression testing on the use cases they present. In short, there's stuff in the documentation that plain doesn't work. If you look at the bottom of the article you'll see the following:

> Please note that the above configuration is tested with Liferay 6.1.1
>   and WSO2 Identity 3.2.3/4.0.0.

I recall I tested this a long time ago, and determined that it wouldn't work with the current version, but that was so long ago that I can't remember why. In any case, the approach presented for integrating Liferay was offered at a time where Liferay didn't have the ability to use standardized authentication protocols like SAML. Now that it does, you probably want to do it in a standards compliant manner instead of using an authentication interface Liferay only promotes using for proprietary authentication systems.

My suggestion is that if you are using Liferay portal enterprise with LDAP that you use the built-in SAML connector. If you aren't using Enterprise, there are some compatible authenticator extensions in the extensions store that will also integrate with Liferay. If you configure Liferay to be a client against WSO2 and then integrate Liferay to LDAP on the backend, it also allows Liferay to be used as a user dashboard instead of the jaggery based one that comes in the product.